# Jbpm 7.39 failures

Tags: java, jbpm

I downloaded bpm-installer-full-7.39.0.Final.zip from here https://download.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.39.0.Final/
and trying to install it.
In contrast to 7.33 there's no ddl-scripts folder under /db path.
Then, when I made run

- ant install.demo.noeclipse
- ant start.demo.noeclipse

I kept seeing lots of similar traces:

```
2020-08-10 12:26:58,268 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/default-kieserver error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/default-kieserver response code 500
2020-08-10 12:27:08,284 INFO  [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 'http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism
2020-08-10 12:27:08,299 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/default-kieserver: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.kie.server.api.marshalling.json.JSONMarshaller$2.verifyBaseTypeValidity(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperConfig;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/PolymorphicTypeValidator;
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:346)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:456)
```

However, PUT http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/default-kieserver works fine and returns 201 status. Client-side cannot handle the response? then why is server response 500 according to the logs?

And GUI (process management) says:

```
Attention
Execution Server Unavailable
There is currently no server connected.
```

Does anyone have a guess what I am doing wrong?

PS I installed jbpm v 7.33 on the same PC a couple of months ago without a headache.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work(at least traces are gone and GUI is not throwing warnings).

I went into jbpm-installer-7.39.0.Final\wildfly-18.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\fasterxml\jackson
and upgraded

- jackson-annotations
- jackson-core
- jackson-databind

up to 2.10.4 version as exactly this version is used for jbpm .war packages.
I am wondering how they delivered such untested and raw version!